# How to run groups of unit tests with gradle in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, gradle

I'm trying to run a specific group of unit tests on our CI server and not in our dev environment.  I've tried a few approaches

1)  Using JUnit categories.  I couldn't get this to work with gradle

2)  Using ./gradlew test --tests *ServiceTest

This never found my tests.

3)  Trying to use build variants to include / exclude certain tests.  This didn't seem flexible enough.

Is there any concrete example on how to do this?

Comment: I've been dealing with this whole week, ended up putting all (unit, integration) tests in androidTest directory and grouping them by classnames - there are two testsuites for Unit/Integration (filtering tests with http://www.johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp), and I just pick the correct suite I want to run.